# Trying to get property of non-object Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, compiler-errors

I have written this piece of code inside the **App\Post.php** file.

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

}
```

I have written it inside the **routes.php**

```
Route::get('/{id}', function($id){

    return Post::find($id)->user->name;

});
```

I am getting the following error when I go to test the code.

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Either `Post::find($id)` or `Post::find($id)->user` is not an object

Comment: @Scuzzy How can I make it an object?

Comment: That depends on what `Post::find($id)` is returning, is it actually finding something or is it returning boolean false etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Let's redefine your model  
**In App\User.php**

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

**In App\Post.php**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**So you can access from each other like**

```
//Get User from Post
$user = Post::find($id)->user;

//Get Post collection from User
$posts = User::find($id)->posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your result and code like this :

1. does your  Post::find($id); return a value or empty? if it's empty then you need to check your table probably the id is not exist
2. check your table for the each id on the table and refine your model like this :

**App\Post.php**

```
public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'the_foreign_key_Post_in_users', 'primary_key_in_Post');
    }
```

**App\User.php**

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','the_foreign_key_POst_in_users');
  }
```